# UTF-8 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, innerhtml

I use Javascript to get data in a HTML pages define with a charset UTF8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

my javascript method is load with a charset UTF8

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../ressources/js/test.js"></script>
```

but i have a encode problem, when i get data with "innerHTML"

ex: salari�s

is there something I missed ?

Comment: How are you getting the data? Where are you getting it from? What are you doing to it before you display it? Do you have a (real) HTTP header that say a different content-type is being used? Have you checked that you have actually saved the data using UTF-8 and you aren't just slapping a UTF-8 label on a document that is actually ISO-8859-1, Windows 1252 or something else?

Comment: The fact that your code claims that the HTML and JS data is encoded in UTF-8 doesn't mean that it is. Have you checked, e.g. with file (http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) or some hexadecimal editor?

Comment: for example: i have an Article  with a heading and a "read more" link. I use a innertHtml on the heading and put the string in the "read more" title. it's correctly display in the heading, not in the title.

Comment: i check: my js and html file are encoded in UTF-8

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The encoding of the files must be set to UTF8.

Comment: if you use Dreamweaver then try this: http://www.fanhow.com/knowhow:Change_page_encoding_in_Dreamweaver_27468409

Comment: i check: my js and html file are encoded in UTF-8. i only use notepad ++

Comment: sorry all, it was my encoding js pages... you are right.

i convert it with notepad++

thanks