# dyve autocomplete transliteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, transliteration

I am using **dyve autocomplete** jquery plugin.The plugin works really well, but when i try to do some transliteration the plugin doesn't work.

**Some details:**
**The results from the database are always in cyrillic**.When the user start to type in cyrillic everything works OK.But when the user start to type in latin, in the backend the latin characters are converted to cyrillic ones, before being submitted to the database.
Then the results are returned as usual to the frontend, but nothing gets displayed.

Does somebody has any idea how to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the encoding of the data coming from your database? javascript uses UTF-16 for encoding characters so that might be something to look into.

Comment: utf-8.I will try to convert the db result first, before sending it to js.Thanks Kyle!

Comment: actually you shouldn't need to convert your database data. Just make sure your files are all encoded in utf-8

Comment: Yes, the conversion didn't do the trick.I believe is something related to the way that particular plugin assembles the autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: Yea, encoding errors can be tricky to track down. The plugin could be doing things that are ignorant of encodings, which could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

To expound on my comments you should make sure everything is dealing with data in UTF-8. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790593/utf-8-and-javascript) for more details. Also make sure all your doctype headers are all have the correct encoding declarations.

Comment: i think i have found the problem(not absolutely sure yet).In essence when the input box content is in latin and the response is in cyrillic the plugin compares the two and because they don't match nothing is suggested.But for now this is nothing more than a guess.Thank again, Kyle!