# Characters outside of ASCII are not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display characters outside ASCII but it doesn't work. I only get scrambled characters. The JavaScript file should also be encoded in UTF-8, at least IntelliJ says so. What is missing or causing the error?

I have this in the index.html (which also has its charset set to UTF-8).

```
<script src="javascript/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Just trying to output

```
console.log("Å");
```

I have this in the index.html file. It is an AngularJs application.

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify UTF-8 encoding in your HTML file. [Here are some ways](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#quicklookup).

Check if your JavaScript file is really UTF-8-encoded (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790593/utf-8-and-javascript)).

Comment: But I have already done that. It is an angularjs application. I don't know if that is special? See updated question.

Comment: It was the file that wasn't saved in UTF-8. It was labeled as such though.